# My Bluetooth is connect, but the driver is not showing

Tags: kali-linux, audio, bluetooth

I have a JBL Bluetooth speaker. And usually it doesn't have a problem until my recent question earlier about [Bluetooth](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/676403/connecting-to-bluetooth-but-connection-failed-no-audio-endpoints-registered) :)

And today's problem is my device is connected, but the device is not showing up in volume control. I try to reinstall `blueman` but it still not working. By the way, I'm dual booted my Linux with Win11. Please help me to resolve this issue, thank you :D

[image: Volume Control]

[image: blutoothctl]

Comment: you tag this with [tag:debian] and [tag:kali-linux]. It can't be both – which is it?

Comment: sorry, I already edit the tag. Thanks